# Simple Password Encryption using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption

1. Below is my `@Bean` method

```java
package com.naveen.entity;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class PasswordEncoder {
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public String encode(String passWord) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

2. Then, I've created `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class as below,

```java
package com.naveen.entity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder extends PasswordEncoder {

}
```

3. Then, I've autowired my `Controller` class & I've added encryption function in my `saveUser()` as below

```java
public class UserController {

    @Autowired 
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/saveUser")
    public int saveUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        String encryptedPassword =passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassWord());
        user.setPassWord(encryptedPassword);
        userService.saveUser(user);
        System.out.println("Inserted data with id: "+ user.getId());
        return 1;
     }

}
```

4. `Service` class as follows,

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userMapper.saveUser(user);
    }
 
}
```

When I run the code, I got the error below:

```
Field passwordEncoder in com.naveen.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.naveen.entity.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.naveen.entity.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

Please help me out to resolve where I went wrong.

Comment: Maybe it can help ideally, `@Bean` should be inside a Configuration class annotated with `@Configuration`. In Spring Security there is an inbuilt Password Encoder with the same name "BCryptPasswordEncoder". Please make sure you are not confusing it anywhere in implementation.

Comment: Despite its name, BCrypt is hashing, not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add `@Component` annotation to `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder extends PasswordEncoder{

}
```

It would work then.

Comment: I've added Component annotation but now the data is stored as NULL in DB.

Comment: And do I need to add any dependencies in pom.xml?

Comment: For null data you will have to check your Spring-Data / JPA configurations. No dependency needed for @Component, its part of spring-core which would already be added to your maven-project. Can you pls accept the answer as it would have solved your original question.

Comment: Only if I add Encoding functionality , data is storing as null. If I remove all the encoding related code, then data is inserted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to PumpkinX's answer put your statements in this order:

```
     String encryptedPassword =passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassWord());
     user.setPassWord(encryptedPassword);
     userService.saveUser(user);
     System.out.println("Inserted data with id: "+ user.getId());
```

Notice, `userService.saveUser(user);` after you read and encode the data? Since you had this statement of top it was causing it to have null value.

Comment: I've given as above, but still it's storing as null in DB. could you please check the possible issue?

Comment: Check your service. Can you share your service code too? I doubt that you are handling the password there too. If thats the case remove it from your service. Or handle this there. Meaning set password either in service or in controller. Service is recommended though.

Comment: I've added service class in above code snippet. Kindly check @Ajay Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late on this. But you are missing the implementation of the encode function.

Just replace the encode function with the below.

```
public String encode(String passWord) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder =
            new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10, new SecureRandom());
    return bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(passWord);

}
```

This will encrypt the password instead of returning the null value.

Answer (score 0):

If You want a real Encryption algorith or encryption mechanism to store passwords in yml file or pass sensitive data to your application , you can try and use *[JASYPT for Spring Boot .](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot)*

Jasypt is a library to encrypt and decrypt spring boot properties in runtime , without worrying about how to handle the encryption logic and decryption logic .

Answer (score 0):

I just twisted your code and able to encode password

1. Bean Class

   ```
    public class PasswordEncoder {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
   ```

   }
2. BCryptPasswordEncoder.java

```
public class PasswordEncoder {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

3. Encoding password

```
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public UserResource saveDto(UserResource userResource) {
         userResource.setPassword(passwordEncoder.bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(userResource.getPassword()));
        return userinfo.save(userResource);
    }
```

4. Encoded password -
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skOYX.png)